# how to show latitude, longitude information in Gmaps Heatmap

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am integrating Gmaps Heatmap with ruby on rails i am able to plot my data on it but unable to show the latitude, longitude and place information in any pop-up box. Following is a method in my controller and i have defined it in route.rb

```
def plot_map
 @records = Place.where("keyword_id = ?",params[:place_keyword_id]).order("created_at desc")
 @places = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@records) do |user, marker|
 marker.lat user.latitude
 marker.lng user.longitude
end
```

i have a view plot_map.html.erb

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(25.6586, -80.3568);
    // map options,
   var myOptions = {
   zoom: 3,
   center: myLatlng
   };
   // standard map
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),       myOptions);
   // heatmap layer
   heatmap = new HeatmapOverlay(map, 
   {
   // radius should be small ONLY if scaleRadius is true (or small    radius is intended)
   "radius": 2,
   "maxOpacity": 1, 
   // scales the radius based on map zoom
  "scaleRadius": true, 
  // if set to false the heatmap uses the global maximum for    colorization
  // if activated: uses the data maximum within the current map   boundaries 
 //   (there will always be a red spot with useLocalExtremas true)
  "useLocalExtrema": true,
// which field name in your data represents the latitude - default    "lat"
   latField: 'lat',
// which field name in your data represents the longitude - default   "lng"
   lngField: 'lng',
// which field name in your data represents the data value - default  "value"
   valueField: 'count'
 }
);

   var testData = {
   max: 8,
   data:<%= raw @places.to_json%>
 };

  heatmap.setData(testData);
});
```

when we click on a heated section. can we display the latitude, longitude in any pop-box like infowindow?